# a simple paradox

Tags: paradox

This is probably the simplest paradox out there and it still confuses me, here it is.

The sentence below is true.

The sentence above is false.

I've known about this one for a few years and it has troubled me ever since. Can someone try and find a solution so I can finally rest?

Comment: Sorry, nope. This is not a puzzle, it's just a self-negation, which makes it off-topic for PSE.

Comment: how is it not a paradox, it seems to be infinitely looping?

Comment: it seems to be an infinitely looping question.

Comment: You could simply say "this sentence is false". [This wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-refuting_idea) contains more informations.

Comment: heres the thing about that, if you just say "this sentence is false" if you proceed, it will say "this sentence is true" which means it is true that the sentence is true.

Comment: when it is false, the only other option is it is true.

Comment: The whole point of a paradox is that it *doesn't make sense*. Rest easy now, you're not alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "solution." If one is true, it automatically contradicts the entire thing. That's the point of a paradox. This is something that's known as a liar's paradox, which you can learn more about [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/).

Comment: see, it is a paradox.

Comment: oh no, my default font is still wingdings XD, whats the gist of the page?